# React-beautiful-dnd not working with react router

Tags: html, reactjs, web, react-router-dom, react-beautiful-dnd

I am working on an app that looks like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-benz-djyjq0?file=/src/App.tsx

I have no idea why the DnD is not working.

Also, the reason I included react-router is because in my local setup, it worked if I wrapped the `<Outlet />` in the `DragDropContext`. I though the issue was because "context clashing" but when I created the sandbox, it wasn't working either way.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?